# Plot paths of equal distance

Tags: algorithm, graph, language-agnostic, drawing

I have two sets of points, specified by their Cartesian coordinates. I need to connect each point from the first set with the corresponding point from the second set by a path drawn on a 2D surface.

Conditions are:

1. Paths must consist only of vertical and horizontal lines (i.e. they should be orthogonal to coordinate axes);
2. Entire drawing must fit into a given rectangle;
3. Tricky part: **all paths must be equal in length**, even if that means having longer and winding paths.

Are there any known solutions to this task? Target language is SKILL (a dialect of Lisp), though implementation doesn't matter much at this point.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET D = 0
LOOP over unique pairs of points
   Calculate d distance between points using orthogonal path
   IF d > D
      SET D = d
LOOP over unique pair of points
   Calculate d distance between points using orthogonal path
   IF d == D
       DRAW path
   ELSE
       DRAW path with extra "jog" of length D - d
```

Here is a sketch of how a path with a "jog" would go

[image]